# ComplexType: Querying based upon analysis of data within

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I'm wanting to see if what I want to do is possible, and if so, how?

The idea is that I store a bunch of products. Then for those products, I have sellers. The sellers have offers for the products. I'd like to offer the buyers some intelligence on the history of seller offers for those products.

So let's say I have a ComplexType field within my Azure Cognitive Search Index called "SellerOffers". That field would have data that looks like this:

```
{
   "offers":[
      {
         "offerid":5,
         "offerPrice":"15.00",
         "offerDate":"9/23/2021"
      },
      {
         "offerid":4,
         "offerPrice":"12.50",
         "offerDate":"8/10/2021"
      },
      {
         "offerid":3,
         "offerPrice":"13.50",
         "offerDate":"7/15/2021"
      },
      {
         "offerid":2,
         "offerPrice":"10.00",
         "offerDate":"6/01/2021"
      },
      {
         "offerid":1,
         "offerPrice":"12.50",
         "offerDate":"5/23/2021"
      }
   ]
}
```

In the data above, you can see that on 6/1/21, the price was only $10.00, and the price is currently $15.00, maybe the seller would still accept $10 (or $12).

Is it possible to ask that question of Azure Cognitive Search?
IE, show me products that had a previous offer where the price was 20% lower than the current offer.

Thank you for any help, I couldn't find any documentation about how such a complex query might be written.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you are looking for is the Semantic Answers feature from Semantic Search, which basically adds cognitive capabilities to Search queries, and allows answers based on queries that are formulated as a question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-answers#prerequisites
I don't know if it is smart enough to understand your question but I think is worth giving it a try, you need to sign up for the public preview first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-search-overview#availability-and-pricing

Comment: Thank you! This looks very awesome, but you can only apply semantic search to the top 50 results in a result set. IE, you can't run a semantic query against the entire index. I wonder if I can accomplish this with a lamda $filter....

Comment: Filters are applied before the Semantic Search is applied, so yes you could filter the results first.